# RegEx false result

Tags: c#, regex

```
 string input = customSearchResult;
 string pattern = @"(?<=link)";
 MatchCollection linkMatches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

 foreach (Match match in linkMatches) { 
    return ResultOutcome += linkMatches.ToString();
 }
 return ResultOutcome += "Fail";
```

I have this code aperture.
I want to display the links from my json output. But my output is always:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.
Greetings, Valeria.

Comment: What do you expect `return` in a `foreach` loop to do? In the first iteration, it will return, ignoring the rest of the matches...

Comment: And what do you expect to capture having regex with only positive look-behind?

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov I want to filter out all links from my json output with only the positiv look-behind, I dont need another look-behind, do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- Your `foreach` loop returns the first match, skipping the rest, and
- Your `foreach` loop calls `ToString` on the `MatchCollection` object.

You can concatenate the matches without a loop, like this:

```
if (linkMatches.Count != 0) {
    return ResultOutcome + string.Join("", linkMatches);
} else {
    return ResultOutcome + "Fail";
}
```

Of course you need to fix your regular expression as well, so that it matches at least *something* after the look-behind anchor.

Comment: @Valeria Did you try the last version, or the previous one?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your code is fine, regex pattern is not fine.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It appears that before the modification OP got at least one mathc, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight all of them

Comment: @dasblinkenlight With this regex only empty string after `link` will be matched.

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov So my regex is bad, isnt it?!

Comment: @dasBlinkenlight Unfortunately I have still this output: System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection, although I've changed my RegEx.

Comment: @Valeria Try adding a cast to `Match`, like this: `return ResultOutcome + string.Join("", linkMatches.Cast<Match>());` You need to add `using System.Linq` at the top for this to compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hello again :-) you mentioned that my foreach loop returns the first match and skipping the rest. Could you explain, why it skipping the rest, please? Do you know a way round the problem, so "tell the loop it should please go throug ALL the matches and do something with them"? I thought this loop is extra for something like that...so you say FOR EACH of my Matches you do this and that, but not FOR ONE (or FOR THE FIRST) do this and that. Ugh confusing :-/

Comment: @Valeria Your `foreach` loop processes only the first item because you have an unconditional `return` statement in it. The only way around this problem is not to put unconditional `return` statements in a loop, i.e. return only after all the processing has been done.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but than, my return, understandably, doesn't know my `Match match` :-( . And what is, when I want to return my `match`? Either I return it after all the processing (so, it gives me an exception because it dont know what the `match` is) or in the loop so it gives me only one match back...

Comment: @Valeria Use `match` inside the loop to construct whatever you are constructing (e.g. append matched values to a string defined before the loop). Then return the string that you constructed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you very much for your explanations! You have given me a great deal of help, really!